# Input spinner If value >0 then select card

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I am developing front end tool for quoting. User should click on card and chose which product to put in basket, having also a input section for quoting (bootstrap-input-spinner) for a user to chose quantity.
You can see project on the next link. 
https://wearenicey.com/projects/quotetool/

Or seeing the little code beneath

Tried with parseInt but not successful. Having Novice experience with Javascript and Jquery, I cannot see the solution.

```html
<div class="card" data-cardSelected>
  <img src="{{root}}assets/img/product-img.jpg" class="card-img-top pt-lg-3 pt-md-2 px-lg-3 px-md-2 pt-2 px-2 pb-1" alt="..." data-cardSelect>
  <a class="btn-floating" data-toggle="collapse" href="#productOne" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="productOne"></a>
  <div class="card-body pb-0 pb-sm-2 pb-md-2 pb-lg-2 px-2 px-md-4 px-lg-4" data-cardSelect>
    <p class="mb-0 mb-sm-2">Title</p>
    <p class="card-text d-none d-md-block">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body pt-0 px-2 px-md-4 px-lg-4 pb-2 pb-md-4 pb-lg-4">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
        <p class="pb-0 mb-0">$3212
          </h5>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 mt-2 mt-md-0 mt-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control-sm" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="1000" step="1" style="display: none;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='number']").inputSpinner();

  $('[data-cardSelect]').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('[data-cardSelected]').toggleClass('selected');
  });
});
```

I think it would be better for a user when inputs any quantity number bigger then 0, card should be selected. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a change listener to your input filed. When it get's triggered, look at the selected amount and add the class 'selected' or remove it

```js
// add a listener to the change-, paste-, keyup- and input-event of all 
// inputs in cards with type number
$(".card input[type=number]").on('change paste keyup input', function() {
  // get the value of the input element
  var value = $(this).val();
  // setv the class depending on value
  if(value > 0){
    $(this).parent('.card').addClass('selected');
  }else{
    $(this).parent('.card').removeClass('selected');
  }
});

function changeInput(target, delta){
  // get the card of the given element
  var card = $(target).parent('.card');
  // get the input element
  var input = card.find('input[type=number]');
  
  // get the current value as integer
  var value = parseInt("0"+input.val());
  // get the borders
  var min = input.attr('min');
  var max = input.attr('max');
  // add the delta and check the borders
  value = Math.max(min, Math.min(max, value+delta)); 
  // set the new value
  input.val(value);
  // trigger the changed event
  input.trigger('change');
}
```

```css
.card {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: RGBA(0,0,0,0.25);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.card img {
  height: 150px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.card.selected {
  background-color: RGBA(0,0,255,0.50);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1584/741?image=0">
  <button onclick="changeInput(this, -1)">-</button>
  <input type="number" value="0" min="0" max="1000" step="1">
  <button onclick="changeInput(this, 1)">+</button>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1584/741?image=10">
  <button onclick="changeInput(this, -1)">-</button>
  <input type="number" value="0" min="0" max="1000" step="1">
  <button onclick="changeInput(this, 1)">+</button>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1584/741?image=100">
  <button onclick="changeInput(this, -1)">-</button>
  <input type="number" value="0" min="0" max="1000" step="1">
  <button onclick="changeInput(this, 1)">+</button>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1584/741?image=200">
  <button onclick="changeInput(this, -1)">-</button>
  <input type="number" value="0" min="0" max="1000" step="1">
  <button onclick="changeInput(this, 1)">+</button>
</div>
```

EDIT: add code snippet to prove the concept

Comment: Thanks on your quick answer, but unfortunately it's not working. I've just copy pasted your code, and added bracket which was missing.

Comment: Opps, sorry. I've updated the answer and add a code snipped to prove the concept. You have to modify it for your code.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works, just having problem to target (modify) card in my code I have.

Comment: Yap, got it with .parrents()